# Branchless avoid division by zero

Tags: optimization, assembly

Say I have piece of code along the lines of

```
double test(double value, double denom) {
  return (denom == 0 ? 0 : value/denom);
}
```

which gets compiled to:

```
    movapd  %xmm0, %xmm2
    xorpd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm1
    jnp .L8
.L5:
    movapd  %xmm2, %xmm0
    divsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L8:
    jne .L5
    rep
    ret
```

Is there some neat way to void branching? Arch in question is X86-64.
Eg PPC has select instruction, is there an equivalent in X86-64 ISA?

Comment: Not for the `xmm` registers, no. You could use the usual masking tricks or maybe `blendvps` if you have a machine with that, but my feeling is that you are better off with the branch.

Comment: in x86 conditional moves are only available for integer registers

Comment: As an aside, should you even have this test? Returning zero as the result for a zero divisor is highly misleading.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that's current logic, i am only looking into optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have exceptions turned off, it's a simple matter to mask the result:

```
xorpd %xmm2, %xmm2
cmpneqsd %xmm1, %xmm2
divsd %xmm1, %xmm0
andpd %xmm2, %xmm0
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

The branch prediction machinery is pretty good these days.

Unless you actually *have* zero divisors with some nonzero frequency, the branch predictor is going to figure out that the jnp statistically doesn't branch and simply fall through without any loss of performance.

Have you measured this, and seen any loss of performance over leaving out the test?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is fairly good mix of zero and non-zero denoms and branching does *seem* to take some time.

Comment: What happens if you try it without a bunch of zero divisors?If you get a real mix, then the branch predictor will likely fail and you want some kind of predicated move instead, or simply disable floating traps.